# How to prevent to disable game object while game is running in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-engine, software-design

I am developing a simple game.I want to stay game object stable.However,While I am running game,game objects miss suddenly.How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

You should find out whats turning gameobjects off but you could try something like

```
void OnDisable() {
gameObject.SetActive(true); // Results in the error "Game Object is already being activated or deactivated
}
```

or

```
void OnDisable() {
StartCoroutine(ReEnable());
}

public IEnumerator ReEnable() {
yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.1f);
gameObject.SetActive(true);
}
```

Comment: I will try it.Thank you sir.

Comment: This does not work, at least in Unity 2021